# How do you trim the audio file's end using SoX?

Tags: audio, trim, sox

Using Sox, how do I shorten an audio file by 5 seconds, trimming from the end?

For example, this is how to trim a file from the beginning:

```
    sox input output trim 5000
```

This is how to add 5 seconds of silence to the end:

```
    sox input output pad 0 5000
```

Comment: I asked a similar question about SoX and it got cancelled "This question is off-topic. It is closed and not accepting answers.
Question: SoX Join WAV files Win

Feedback: This question is off-topic because it’s about general computing hardware and software. Edit the question so it’s on-topic."

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The syntax is `sox input output trim <start> <duration>`

e.g. `sox input.wav output.wav trim 0 00:35` will output the first 35 seconds into `output.wav`.

(you can know what the length is using `sox input -n stat`)

From the [SoX documentation](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) on the `trim` command:

> Cuts portions out of the audio. Any number of *positions* may be given; audio is not sent to the output until the first *position* is reached. The effect then alternates between copying and discarding audio at each *position*. Using a value of 0 for the first *position* parameter allows copying from the beginning of the audio.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> sox infile outfile trim 0 10
> ```
>
> will copy the first ten seconds, while
>
> ```
> play infile trim 12:34 =15:00 -2:00
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> play infile trim 12:34 2:26 -2:00
> ```
>
> will both play from 12 minutes 34 seconds into the audio up to 15 minutes into the audio (i.e. 2 minutes and 26 seconds long), then resume playing two minutes before the end of audio.

Per [dpwe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667081/how-do-you-trim-the-audio-files-end-using-sox#comment48663188_10418603), the *position* values are interpreted as being relative to the previous *position*, unless they start with `=` (in which case they are relative to the start of the file) or `-` (in which case they are relative to the end of the file).

So, trimming five seconds off the end would be `sox input output trim 0 -5`

Comment: This cuts the file to the good length but this adds an annoying click noise at the end.

Comment: You can use `sox input output trim <start> <duration>`, or `sox input output trim <start> =<end>`.  The full `trim` syntax accepts any number of pairs of `<position>` arguments, which are interpreted as relative to the preceding position by default, or relative to the start of the file if preceded by '=', or relative to the end of the file (if known) if preceded by '-'.  Only the sound between each pair of positions is output.

Comment: See my solution below for a way to avoid a click at the end, using a tiny fade.

Comment: @yonix Would love your thoughts on : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161567/silence-out-regions-of-audio-based-on-a-list-of-time-stamps-using-sox-and-pyth

Answer (score 11):

Above command is wrong, it will get you last 5 seconds only. You actually need to use:

```
sox input output reverse trim 5 reverse
```

which will cut 5 seconds from end of the file.

Comment: I figured that there is an easier way to do it. Adding the minus will do the rest. Following will cut the last 5 sec
`sox input output trim 0 -5`

Comment: Let's not reverse twice an audio stream, just to get it's end.

Answer (score 7):

I'm new to SoX but have noticed this page frequently shows up in search results for audio trimming and will be seen by many trying to do similar things.

As such I wanted to provide what I have found to be the best solution personally.

I experienced the same 'click' at file end which [John Smith Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667081/how-do-you-trim-the-audio-files-end-using-sox#comment46523564_10418603) had mentioned. This suggested a brief fade out could remove any glitching artefacts as the audio finishes and sure enough it works. It's acceptance of a negative value for the fadeout position parameter to indicate the time before the end of audio is the key.

So I can see no better way to achieve the OP's aim than this:

```
sox full_length.wav trimmed.wav fade 0 -5 0.01
```

Parameter 1 is '0' so there is no fade in.
Parameter 2 removes the last 5 seconds
Parameter 3 uses a 10ms fade

Comment: Providing negative value to the stoptime of `fade` is not working for me on SoX v14.4.1.

Comment: @dingles are you able to help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161567/silence-out-regions-of-audio-based-on-a-list-of-time-stamps-using-sox-and-pyth